# MongoDB - find if a field value is contained in a given string

Tags: mongodb

Is it possible to query documents where a specific field is contained in a given string?

for example if I have these documents:

```
{a: 'test blabla'},
{a: 'test not'}
```

I would like to find all documents that field `a` is fully included in the string `"test blabla test"`, so **only the first document would be returned**.

I know I can do it with `aggregation` using `$indexOfCP` and it is also possible with `$where` and `mapReduce`. I was wandering if it's possible to do it in `find` query using the standard MongoDB operators (e.g., $gt, $in).

thanks.

Comment: `{a: 'test'}` is also fully contained in `"test blabla test"`. Are you looking for the closest containing match ?

Comment: @Veeram I'm sorry, I fixed the documents. (it's confusing for me also :D )

Comment: The feature request for this is still open https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-13902

Answer (score 1):

I can think of 2 ways you could do this:

## Option 1

Using **$where**:

```
db.someCol.find( { $where: function() { return "test blabla test".indexOf(this.a) > -1; } }
```

**Explained:** Find all documents whose value of field "a" is found WITHIN some given string.

This approach is universal, as you can run any code you like, but less recommended from a performance perspective. For instance, it cannot take advantage of indexes. Read full $where considerations here: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/where/#considerations

## Option 2

Using regex matching trickery, ONLY under certain circumstances; below is an example that only works with matching that the field value is found as a starting substring of the given string:

```
db.someCol.find( { a : /^(t(e(s(t( (b(l(a(b(l(a( (t(e(s(t)?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?$/ } )
```

**Explained:** Break up the components of your "should-be-contained-within" string and match against all sub-possibilities of that with regex.

For your case, this option is pretty much insane, but it's worth noting as there may be specific cases (such as limited namespace matching), where you would not have to break up each letter, but some very finite set of predetermined parts. And in that case, this option could still make use of indexes, and not suffer the $where performance pentalties (as long as the complexity of the regex doesn't outweigh that benefit :)

Comment: thanks, but as I said in the question, I'm know it's possible with `$where` and some other possibilities with `aggregate`. I wanted to know if it's possible using  standard MongoDB operators.

Comment: Yea a variation of option 2 adjusted to certain cases. Otherwise, the feature request mentioned by JohnnyHK possibly in the future. GL

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to search .

```
db.company.findOne({"companyname" : {$regex : ".*hello.*"}});
```

Comment: this is the other way arround, if the string is contained in the field.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **Mongo v3.6+**, you can use [$expr](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v4.4/reference/operator/query/expr/).

As you mentioned `$indexOfCP` can be used to get index, here it will be

```
{ 
   "$expr": {
       {$ne : [{$indexOfCP: ["test blabla test", "$a"]}, -1]}
   }
}
```

The field name should be prefixed with a dollar sign ($), as `$expr` allows *filters* from aggregation pipeline.